# HH/MMの型を'01' | '02' | '03' | ... | '60'で定義するTypeScriptの良い書き方募集

Tags: typescript

```js
time {
  HH: string
  MM: string
}
```

のようなオブジェクトが存在していて、HHとMMはAPIから文字列で取得すると仮定します。

HHとMMには'01'...'60'のゼロ埋めされた文字列の数字のみが代入できるようにしたいです。

やろうと思えばHH: '1' or HH: 'aaaa'のようなゼロ埋めしてない文字列やアルファベットが入ってしまうのでいやです。

```js
HH: '00' | '01' | '02' | '03' | ... | '58' | '59' | '60'
```

のように手で書いてもいいのですがTSらしくないので何とかして型変数とかを駆使して短い1行にまとめたいです。

良いアイディアがあればご教授いただきたいです。

TSのバージョンは3.9ですが、4.0以降でも良い書き方があればぜひぜひ募集しておりますmm

Comment: HHとMMを取得するAPIの仕様は、どうなっているのですか？
APIが'01'...'60'のゼロ埋めされた文字列の数字のみを返すのであれば、安心してAPIからのデータをHHやMMに代入できます。

HHは時間ですよね？　だったら、`01`...'12'か、'00'...'11'かに制限しないといけないのではないでしょうか？　"37時12分"というような表現を普通はしませんから。

Comment: レガシーなシステムを新しくしていて、APIで受け取ったオブジェクトを上書きするような実装が存在するかもしれない状況で、実際文字列の'01'がいつの間にか数値の1になっているバグが存在します。
今回TypeScriptで安全にデータを扱いたく、このような質問をさせていただいています。

Comment: あと、今回は24:00をすぎる時間も扱うシステムなので、ある時刻から45:00すぎた場合の時間の加算や引き算があります。

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript 4.1以降の機能で**Template literal types**を使うと表現ができるようになるかと思います。まだ正式リリース版ではないので、Playgroundなどで試してみると良いと思います。

### DEMO

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwMYENgB4DKBGKEAewECAJgM5QICuAtgEYQBOANFJgEx6HHmW0OMAfFAC8UAAYASAN44AvjI5zxAbgCwAKFCQ2ASwQBzADYQAIroO7gAOX5NRUAAxQAPlFxvObgMyuoAFj8AVj8ANj8Adj8ADj8ATnUNTW1oAAlUh3hkNHRnN2xWTH1jMwsrW3omYTcs1Ax2Vjz3Py8oXzd-QUSUqABZXszEOty-DyhW9oDgwuKTc0sbOyE-ACJQxxXEzX0iRgAzFCRoABVdGmhpTShrqAALW4AuKHTEm6gaGif+xLlNTSREGRgFBgGcIE9TucHJcNG97k8Vth2CtmFcbh8EUE4ijNHJEkA)

### サンプルコード

`infer`など使えば境界値を厳しく表現できますが、簡単で直感的な例として次のような感じにかけます。

```js
type Concat<S1 extends number, S2 extends number> = `${S1}${S2}`;
type SingleDigitNumber = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type HH = Concat<0 | 1, SingleDigitNumber> | Concat<2, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4>;
type MM = Concat<0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5, SingleDigitNumber> | "60";

interface Time {
    hh: HH;
    mm: MM;
}

const time: Time = {
    hh: "12",
    mm: "59",
};
```

[image: Playgroundの補完]

### 参考

- [Template literal types and mapped type 'as' clauses #40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Comment: なるほど！Template literal typesで書くとこのような感じになるんですね！！すぐ使えたらいいのですが、導入したTSのバージョンが3.9なので(お伝えしてなかった)、既存だと難しそうですかね。。。

Comment: [Release Plan](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40124)によれば2020/11/17にリリース予定日だそうです。今は型で頑張れないのでValidationやテストで担保しておいて、リリースされて利用できるようなってから型をあてるワークアラウンドをすると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 時が経ち、[TypeScript 4.1がリリース](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/)されました。バージョンアップさえすれば利用可能になるでしょう。

Comment: 4.1リリースされましたね！